# PassportJS Not Recognizing Password Change

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-local

I created added some password reset functionality to my sign up flow that allows users to change their password, but when a user resets their password, they are unable to login with the new password and I receive a consoled `Server Error`. I'm wondering if this has to do with updating the user password outside of the passportjs logic or maybe because my password isn't hashed on the update?

Here is the console log:

```
GET /login 200 9.507 ms - 1793
GET /stylesheets/styles.css 304 1.093 ms - -
Database query triggered
Executing (default): SELECT `user_id`, `first_name` AS `firstName`, `last_name` AS `lastName`, `email`, `password`, `organization_id` AS `organizationId`, `reset_password_token` AS `resetPasswordToken`, `reset_password_expires` AS `resetPasswordExpires`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `user` AS `user` WHERE `user`.`email` = 'test@gmail.com' LIMIT 1;
Server Error
POST /login 302 16.169 ms - 56
GET /login 200 10.926 ms - 1862
```

**Here is my password update route:**

```
var express = require('express');
var siteRoutes  = express.Router();
var path = require('path');
var async = require('async');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var sgTransport = require('nodemailer-sendgrid-transport');
var moment = require('moment');
var url = require('url');
var passport = require(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..','./config/passport.js'));
var models = require('../models/db-index');


    /*====   /RESET     ====*/

    siteRoutes.route('/reset/:token')

        .get(function(req, res){
            var urlPath = url.parse(req.url).pathname.split('/');
            var urlToken = urlPath[2];
            console.log(urlToken);
            models.User.findOne({
                where: {
                    resetPasswordToken: req.params.token,
                    resetPasswordExpires: {
                        $gt: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
                    }
                }
            }).then(function(){
                res.render('pages/app/reset-password.hbs',{
                    urlToken: urlToken
                });
            })          
        })


        .post(function(req, res){
            async.waterfall([
                function(done){
                    models.User.update({
                        password: req.body.password,
                        resetPasswordToken: null,
                        resetPasswordExpires: null
                    }, { where: {
                        resetPasswordToken: req.body.token,
                        resetPasswordExpires: {
                            $gt: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
                        }
                    }})
                // Nodemailer
                var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(sgTransport(options));

                var mailOptions = {
                    from: '"Tester" <test@test.com',
                    to: 'test@gmail.com', //Replace with Email
                    subject: 'Your password has been changed',
                    text: 'Hello,\n\n' +
              'This is a confirmation that the password for your account ' + 'test@gmail.com' + ' has just been changed.\n'
                };

                transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
                    if(error){
                        return console.log(error + 'During Post');
                    }
                    console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);

                })
                }
            ])
            res.redirect('/login');
        });
```

**Here is my login routing:**

```
/*====  Login   ====*/


    siteRoutes.route('/login')

        .get(function(req, res){
            res.render('pages/site/login.hbs',{
                error: req.flash('error')
            });
        })

        .post(passport.authenticate('local', {
            successRedirect: '/app',
            failureRedirect: '/login',
            failureFlash: 'Invalid email or password.'
        }));
```

**Here is the user model:**

```
var bcrypt   = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

var User = sequelize.define('user', {
    user_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    firstName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        field: 'first_name'
    },
    lastName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        field: 'last_name'
    },
    email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        isEmail: true,
        unique: true,
        set: function(val) {
            this.setDataValue('email', val.toLowerCase());
        }
    },
    password: DataTypes.STRING,
    organizationId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        field: 'organization_id',
        allowNull: true
    },
    resetPasswordToken: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        field: 'reset_password_token'
    },
    resetPasswordExpires: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        field: 'reset_password_expires'
    }
}, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    classMethods: {
        associate: function(db) {
            User.belongsToMany(db.Organization, { through: 'member', foreignKey: 'organizationId'})
        },
        generateHash: function(password) {
            return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
        },
    },
    instanceMethods: {
        validPassword: function(password) {
            return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
        },
    },


});
    return User;
}
```

**Here is the passportjs logic:**

```
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var models = require('../app/models/db-index');

/*====  Passport Configuration  ====*/

// Serialize sessions
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log("User ID: " + user.user_id + " is serializing");
  done(null, user.user_id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user_id, done) {
  models.User.find({where: {user_id: user_id}}).then(function(user){
    console.log("User ID: " + user.user_id + " is deserializing");
    done(null, user);
  }).error(function(err){
    done(err, null);
  });
});

//Login logic
passport.use('local', new LocalStrategy({
    passReqToCallback: true,
    usernameField: 'email'
},  function(req, email, password, done) {
        console.log("Database query triggered");
        //Find user by email
        models.User.findOne({
            where: { 
            email: req.body.email
            }
        }).then(function(user) {
            if (!user) {
                done(null, false, { message: 'The email you entered is incorrect' }, console.log("Unknown User"));
            } else if (!user.validPassword(password)){
                done(null, false, console.log("Incorrect Password"));
            } else {
                console.log("User match");
                done(null, user);
            }
        }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log("Server Error");
            return done(null, false);
        });
    }));

//Sign Up Logic
passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
    passReqToCallback: true,
    usernameField: 'email'
}, function(req, email, password, done){
    models.User.findOne({
        where: {
            email: email
        }
    }).then(function(existingUser){
        if (existingUser)
            return done(null, false, req.flash('error', 'Email already exists.'));
        if (req.user) {
            var user = req.user;
            user.firstName = firstName;
            user.lastName = lastName;
            user.email = email;
            user.password = models.User.generateHash(password);
            user.save().catch(function(err){
                throw err;
            }).then(function(){
                done(null, user, req.flash('error', 'All fields need to be filled in'));
            });
        } else {
            var newUser = models.User.build({
                firstName: req.body.firstName,
                lastName: req.body.lastName,
                email: req.body.email,
                password: models.User.generateHash(password)
            });

            newUser.save().then(function(){
                done(null, newUser);
            }).catch(function(err){
                done(null, false, console.log(err));
            });
        }
    }).catch(function(e){
        done(null, false, req.flash('error', 'All fields need to be filled in'),console.log(e.email + e.message));
    })
}));

module.exports = passport;
```

Comment: No, there's no relation with passport logic, when you updated your user password you just need to generate the password hash (bcrypt) again. Passport internals don't need to know that stuff, the encrypt/decrypt, hashing and auth is always provided by your logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you forget to generate your password again.

```
.post(function(req, res){
  async.waterfall([
    function(done){
      models.User.update({
        password: models.User.generateHash(req.body.password)
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you! Is it safe to assume that my 'local-signup' method in the passport file was throwing the error because it is being set to `models.User.generateHash(password)` so it is looked for a hashed value?